# How to do get http request in Android background service on specific website?

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview, xmlhttprequest

I have a WebView where user enter in account. When the app is alive I have Service witch do http request GET on this page using JavaScript and JavaScript Interfece in WebView but when app go to background I can't do this my Service will destroy.

How can I continue to do GET request in background? Should I have to enter in user account using POST request? What's about CORS error?

I'm new in Http Request and Android Web developing I hope you guys can help me:)